# Classify georeferenced image based on colour in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, classification, image, image-classification

I have a georeferenced image (attached) that I want to classify into a raster, where raster values correspond to the colours in the image.

Low (green) = 1
Medium (yellow) = 2
High (red) = 3
All other colours = 0

How can I do this in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: reclassify by table (via Raster Analysis in processing toolbox) https://fivequestionz.home.blog/2020/02/08/how-to-reclassify-a-raster-layer-in-qgis/

Comment: Do it manually by creating a vector layer and draw: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/digitizing_basics.html